# how to replace group of texts in a link

Tags: php, regex, replace, inline, src

I have a Regex that detects a certain type of link.The detection part works fine its the replacing part that dosen't work.I tried replace on http://regex101.com/

the code:

```
$link="cover_photos_s/yasinallana1984751717_post_notif_aurora_kuenzli_big.jpg";

//regex
$reg_for_key="~((cover_photos_s\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(_post_notif_)(\w+)(.[a-z]+))~i";

if(preg_match_all($reg_for_key,$link))
{
//the replace string goes here
}
```

I need to replace the `_post_notif_` in the src with `_thumb_` .How do i do it?

Solved thnx to @OnlineCop

Comment: Does the replacement `\2\3_thumb_\5\6` not work? http://regex101.com/r/aD8jH5

Comment: Why don't you try `(_post_notif_)` and replace the match with the desired one using `preg_replace()`. [demo](http://regex101.com/r/vW4jK5)

Comment: @OnlineCop put this as an answer so tht i can vote you up . It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below regex, replace the second captured group with `_thumb_`,

```
^(cover_photos_s\/[a-z0-9A-Z]+)(_\w+?_\w+?_)(.*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jF6kS5)

Your php code would be,

```
<?php
$link = "cover_photos_s/yasinallana1984751717_post_notif_aurora_kuenzli_big.jpg";
$reg_for_key = "~^(cover_photos_s\/[a-z0-9A-Z]+)(_\w+?_\w+?_)(.*)$~";
$replacement = "$1_thumb_$3";
echo preg_replace($reg_for_key, $replacement, $link);
?>  //=> cover_photos_s/yasinallana1984751717_thumb_aurora_kuenzli_big.jpg
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/lfiTHl)

**Explanation:**

- `(cover_photos_s\/[a-z0-9A-Z]+)` Captures upto the `_` which was present just before to the string `post`.
- `(_\w+?_\w+?_)` From the underscore, it matches the shortest word characters upto the first underscore, thus it matches the string `_post`. Again  it matches upto the string `notif` because of `?` operator after `+` symbol makes the regex engine to match the shortest possibility plus the following `_` symbol. Thus in turn regex engine capture the second group of characters.
- All the characters next to them are captured into third group.
- In the replacement part, replacing the second group with your string will give the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

**If it's a literal: use `str_replace`**

If `_post_notif_` is a literal, you can use:

```
$replaced = str_replace("_post_notif_","",$link);
```

**If it's a variable: use `\K`**

If `_post_notif_` is actually a variable that always has 3 underscores, like `_post_notif_`, then you can do a straight replacement using this regex:

```
[^/]+/[^_]+\K_(?:[^_]+_){2}
```

In PHP:

$replaced = preg_replace('~[^/]+/[^*]+\K*(?:[^*]+*){2}~', '', $link);

**Explanation**

- `[^/]+` matches any chars that are not a `/'
- `/` matches the `/`
- `[^_]+`  matches any chars that are not a `_'
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final
- `_` matches the first `_`
- `(?:[^_]+_){2}` matches the rest of the variables (no-underscores + 1 underscore, twice)

Comment: FYI added option for `_abc_def_` variable substitution with PHP code and explanation. :)